# Do I need my application baked into the AMI to use auto scaling or can I use ansible for deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, java, deployment, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that deploys my java app running on port 8080. It does this:

1. Unregister instance from ELB
2. Bring Java application offline
3. Update RPM package with new jar file
4. Bring Java application online
5. Re-register instance in ELB

If I wish to use AWS auto-scaling, do I need to bake the java app into the image or can I still use my current Ansible deploy script?

Answer (score 2):

> If I wish to use AWS auto-scaling, do I need to bake the java app into
>   the image or can I still use my current Ansible deploy script?

It depends on how quickly you want newly-added instances to be up and running. If you don't mind a higher amount of lag before they can start serving requests, then sure, use something like `ansible-pull` to deploy your changes on boot. Otherwise, bake your application and configuration into the AMI.